# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): setCatalogItem is not a function не получается полученные данные с firebase поместить в state

Tags: reactjs, axios

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'


//components
import Header from "./components/header/Header";
import Footer from "./components/footer/Footer";

//pages
import Catalog from "./pages/catalog/Catalog";
import Service from "./pages/services/Service";
import Info from "./pages/info/Info";
import Delivery from "./pages/delivery/Delivery";
import Contacts from "./pages/contacts/Contacts";
import Admin from "./pages/admin/Admin";
import axios from "axios";



function App() {

    const {catalogItem, setCatalogItem} = useState([])


    console.log(catalogItem)
    useEffect(function catalogHandler() {
        axios.get('https://kutec-bd-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/base.json')
            .then(response => {
                const catalogItems = response.data
                setCatalogItem(catalogItems)
            })
    },[])

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Router>
            <Header/>
            <main>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Catalog} />
                        <Route path="/services" component={Service} />
                        <Route path="/info" component={Info} />
                        <Route path="/delivery" component={Delivery} />
                        <Route path="/contacts" component={Contacts} />
                        <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
                    </Switch>
            </main>
            <Footer/>
        </Router>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

[image: То что я получаю из Firedase]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ну я получаю данные с firebase и мне нужно поместить их в стэйт, при вызове  setCatalogItem мне выдает Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): setCatalogItem is not a function

Comment: `const [catalogItem, setCatalogItem] = useState([])`

Comment: спасибо, вышло. Смотрел и не уидел